# Implementation of Foldable in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree-traversal

For example, I have some data type. Let it be a binary tree:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

For example, I implemented traversal of the tree:

```
treeFoldt :: Tree t -> [t]
treeFoldt = foldt1 (:) []
```

It works pretty good. But I want to implement `Foldable` interface.

I think, that I should write something like that:

```
instance Foldable Tree where
  foldr = treeFoldt
```

But it does not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could try to tell you where the problem with your code is but sadly you did not give the definition for `foldt1`

But this should work (if your implementation of `treeFoldt` is ok - remember: `[]` is an instance of `Foldable`):

```
instance Foldable Tree where
  foldr f s = Data.Foldable.foldr f s . treeFoldt
```

---

### basic definition using `Monoid`

Anyway, I think the easiest way in this case is to implement just the [`foldMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap) part:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)

instance Foldable Tree where
 foldMap f (Leaf a)     = f a
 foldMap f (Branch l r) = foldMap f l `mappend` foldMap f r
```

and this surely works.

#### Examples / Usage

```
λ> let t = Branch (Branch (Leaf $ Sum 2) (Leaf $ Sum 4)) (Leaf $ Sum 6)
λ> fold t
Sum {getSum = 12}
```

or

```
λ> let t = Branch (Branch (Leaf 2) (Leaf 4)) (Leaf 6)
λ> foldMap Sum t
Sum {getSum = 12}
```

and of course you don't need the `Monoid` part at all - the default implementations work just fine:

```
λ> Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) t
12
```

**by the way**: it's most likely not obvious how `foldr1 (+)` can be expressed just in terms of `foldMap` and it's a nice (advanced) exercise to try to do it on your own :D

---

### external resources

I think [Foldable and Traversable by A. Arnold](https://blog.jakuba.net/2014-07-30-foldable-and-traversable/) is quite a nice blog post on `Foldable` (and `Traversable`) in general - maybe you find it helpful too

Comment: tree data structure is just example. Real question is, what  I have to do, if I have `foldr function` implementation and I want to implement `Foldable interface`.

Comment: if you already have something giving you back a list than you can see the remark I made - if not you have to think about your structure - IMO the easiest way is to use `mappend` and `fmap` as it's just a matter of thinking about how to *flatten*  out the structure and connecting it with `mappend`s

Comment: Although @David doesn't give the definition of `foldt1`, the way he is *using* it makes me suspect he could use `foldr = foldt1`. That this is equivalent to your first version is basically the `build/foldr` fusion rule for lists, if only `foldt1` is polymorphic enough. (Although since he doesn't use `GHC.Exts.build` explicitly, GHC probably won't be able to detect this.)